# Deploy Java web application to root context for glassfish in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, java-ee-6

I have an application that I only ever intend to deploy to the the root ('/') context using glassfish. Unlike with tomcat in eclipse, there are no application specific settings when I double-click the server in the server browser.

I can go to http://localhost:4848 and accomplish this, but when I redeploy after making a change, eclipse deploys the application to '/myapp'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For WAR-only deployments you must do this with a vendor specific configuration file.  For Glassfish you need to set the `<context-root>` tag inside `sun-web.xml` next to the `web.xml` file.

From http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/sundocs/articles/urlrdn.jsp:

```
<sun-web-app>
  <context-root>/mywarname</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

Comment: This seems to be the right path, but even though I have the glassfish facet enabled for my project, this option seems completely ignored. I have no output that tells me why this is ignored.